# Can't compile my trigger in Apex Oracle SQL/PL PLS-00103

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

```
create or replace TRIGGER  lening_bri
BEFORE
update on lening
for each row
begin

if :old.terugbetaald = 'N' and :new.terugbetaald = 'Y' then
  :new.datumterugbetaald := sysdate;
end if;

if :old.terugbetaald = 'Y' and :new.terugbetaald = 'N' then
   :new.datumterugbetaald := NULL;
end if;

if :old.terugbetaald = 'N' and :new.terugbetaald = 'Y' then
   :new.datumterugbetaald := sysdate;
end if;

if old.datumterugbetaald := NULL and :new.datumterugbetaald := NOT NULL then
    :new.terugbetaald := 'Y'
end if;

if :old.datumterugbetaald := NOT NULL and :new.datumterugbetaald := NULL then
    :new.terugbetaald := 'N'
end if;

end;
```

I can't compile it. I get this error every time:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following: . ( * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem then <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
```

For the last two if statements, it has to do the following:

- When I fill in datumterugbetaald, terugbetaald must be set to Yes.
- If I have to clear the datumterugbetaald, Terugbetaald must be set to No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two `if` statements are using the `:=` assignment operator instead of the `=` equality operator. One of the `old` references is missing its leading colon too, and you're missing a couple of statement-ending semicolons.

But you can't compare null with equality checks, [there are dedicated operators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Nulls.html#GUID-CDD7FB76-FC1B-492E-8431-871624FADA27) you have to use instead.

So those should be:

```
if :old.datumterugbetaald IS NULL and :new.datumterugbetaald IS NOT NULL then
    :new.terugbetaald := 'Y';
end if;

if :old.datumterugbetaald IS NOT NULL and :new.datumterugbetaald IS NULL then
    :new.terugbetaald := 'N';
end if;
```

You also need to consider what that column should be set to if neither `if` evaluates to true - if the column you're checking was and stays null, or was and stays not not (including if it changes value).

The same is true for your first three checks too; and your first and third checks seem to be the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction but is still get: PLS-00103

Comment: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following: * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.

Comment: Compilation failed, line 21 (00:19:32) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following: * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.